# How To Implement A MAUI Password Show/Hide In Entry Field

Tags: android, maui

I am trying to implement A Password Visiblity In MAUI App

I tried Two difffernt ways But it Won't Work.

If Know Help Me to Do It

Thanks In Advance .

```
 <StackLayout>
     <Entry Placeholder="PassWord" IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
     <ImageButton Source="eye_on" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End"/>

 </StackLayout>
```

Comment: You should provide the two different ways you tried, but did not work. Post it here, I will answer your question.

Comment: ImageButton has [IsPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/imagebutton) property. One of the easiest way I think is to use bindings. for example, ```<Entry  IsPassword="{Binding Source={x:Reference myImageButton},Path=IsPressed, Converter={StaticResource boolInvertConverter}}"/>```. When ImageButton is pressed, IsPassword set to false (use [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters)), and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you want to hide or show the password Entry while clicking the
> `ImageButton` ?

To show or hide the `Password` text,  you can try to modify the Entry's  `IsPassword` property.
This can be attached to a button by binding the `IsPassword` property to a CheckBox's  `IsChecked` property.
Please refer to the following code:

```
   <Entry IsPassword="{Binding Source={x:Reference hidePassword}, Path=IsChecked }" x:Name="password" ></Entry>
   <CheckBox x:Name="hidePassword"></CheckBox>
```

And if you want the password of the Entry to show when the box is checked and hide when unchecked, you can try to use an [InvertedBoolConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/inverted-bool-converter) from the .Net Maui Community Toolkit.

You can also use MVVM way to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code.

1.create a viewmodel and add a bool variable `IsVisible` to it. Besides,we need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this viewmodel. Once the value is changed, the UI will refresh itself.

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        //add field `IsVisible` here and bind it to the property of the password Entry
        private bool _isVisible;
        public bool IsVisible
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _isVisible, value);
            }
            get { return _isVisible; }
        }

        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _password, value);
            }
            get { return _password; }
        }


        public ICommand ResetCommand { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Password = "123456";

            IsVisible = true;

            ResetCommand = new Command(setVisibleStatus);

        }

        private void setVisibleStatus()
        {
            IsVisible = !IsVisible;
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp"
             x:Class="MauiApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry Placeholder="PassWord" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"   IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Password}"/>
        <ImageButton Source="image1.png"  Command="{ Binding ResetCommand}" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End"  />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```